# macOS Safari can't read localStorage value from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, local-storage

I am opening a pop up window on the event of click. after opening it, the popup contacts our server and get some value. To pass this value to the main window I am storing it in browser localStorage, then I am closing the popUp.

It is working in all browser. IE, Windows Safari, Chrome, Firefox etc. But surprisingly MAC safari can't find the value that I set it in pop up window. Why is this causing ? did I miss something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue regarding Safari is caused by the "block cookies and other website data" preference.

When it's set to "From third parties and advertisers", localStorage isn't shared.

It must be set to "Never".

**See picture:**

[image]

Comment: What's the best way to deal with this problem as a developer? Obviously, you can't go and change a user's browser preferences.